# Ubuntu 16.04 problem with update after installation

Tags: 16.04, package-management

I just started using Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 64bit(using a USB) and after the installation was over I tried to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The error I got is:

[image: Ubuntu_error]

```
Aborted (core dumped)  
Reading package lists... Done  
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test   
-w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh >   
/dev/null; fi'  
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Also, initially I had the Ubuntu has an internal error problem message just right installation (the first time I logged in), which I disabled using

```
sudo sed -i s/enabled=1/enabled=0/ /etc/default/apport
```

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Karel, that was helpful, I managed to run the update.